# Firebase Integration in React Native CLI build error

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am integrating firebase notifications into my react native cli app. I've successfully implemented it for android and it's working. When implementing for IOS I face these build errors.

```
Sandbox: rsync.samba(96045) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-auttrtllrrgyzpdiayoxfiixciav/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built/hermes.framework/Info.plist
Sandbox: rsync.samba(96050) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-auttrtllrrgyzpdiayoxfiixciav/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/.hermes.CvVE5k
```

I am following official [guide](https://rnfirebase.io/)

**What I've tried**

1. Restarting Xcode
2. Restarting Mac
3. Removing /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

**Versions**

4. XCODE: Version 15.3 (15E204a)
5. react: "18.2.0"
6. react-native": "0.73.1"
7. "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.0.0"
8. "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^19.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by going into XCODE and searched for
ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING then toggled it to No.
After this I started build again.